# Is it better to "overload" a function or have two separate functions when dealing with multiple argument types

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a function that takes a array of word objects, and then modifies the word objects. I would like a user to be also be able to use the function on an individual word object, and I'm wondering which is a better approach:

a) have the function type check whether an inputted argument is an object or array and respond accordingly
b) have two functions, one for an obj, and the other for an array.

```
//method 1: accepts either a obj or an array
function wordChecker(element) {
    if (typeof element === 'object') {
        wordCheckerHelperHelper([element]);
    } else if(element instanceof Array) {
        wordCheckerHelper(element);
    } else throw new Error('invalid argument');
};

function wordCheckerHelper(arr) {
    //do something
};

//method 2: separate methods, but the wordCheckerObj method is just a wrapper around the wordCheckerArr method
function wordCheckerArr(arr) {
    //do something
};    

function wordCheckerObj(obj) {
    if(typeof obj !== 'object') throw new Error('invalid argument');
    workCheckerArr([obj]);
}
```

Comment: Opinion-based. However, unless "overloading" adds a *clear* advantage in terms of use (jQuery shows some good examples), use multiple methods *or* require the consume calls it appropriately. In this case I think it's a poor example because it is generally *not* appropriate to convert a non-sequence into a sequence automatically: I would require the consumer to pass an array, even for only one element.

Comment: As @user2864740 has said, it's quite opinion-based. I personally subscribe to the "one function should do only one thing" line of thinking, so I'd create two functions, one which just pipes through to the other. If you're used to Java where you can have multiple definitions then being flexible may suit you better. If you're used to PHP with its one definition, multiple methods may suit you better. Horses for courses - both are totally valid ways to do it

Comment: Well, this is opinion-based so expect the question to be closed soon. Use simple functions that do unambiguous things, at least internally – that way, you can easily write simple tests and keep the functions easy to read and maintain. For the exposed API, you don't want to have access to all these little functions, so you write a few easy to remember publicly exposed methods that accept overloads, do the forking based on arguments, then return the right internal functions. This is usually called the [facade pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/facade).

Comment: You could make the function variadic and then either call it or apply it to the value/values you have.

Comment: it would make sense to have something like modifyObject and modifyObjects. your modifyObjects would just make use of modifyObject internally.that's my opinion. it helps to keep your code meaningful

Comment: keep things pure. no overloading for me.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript libraries tend to use first approach, i.e. accept any type of argument and try to deal with it somehow. I guess this is mostly because of JavaScript dynamic nature, users would quite often don't know (or not sure) about the type of object they received from other system/library. Type detection in JavaScript could be quite tedious, and user code would end up being a massive amount of `if`s and `switch`es, so this types of checks are better encapsulated on library level.